# 'TypeError: Cannot initialize connector undefined: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined'

Tags: loopbackjs, connector

I'm using **loopback3.x**. I want to integrate 3rd party APIs with loopback. For that while using loopback-connector-rest shows the error '**TypeError: Cannot initialize connector undefined: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined**'. How to fix it?

Datasource configuration

```
   "restDataSource": {
    "name": "restDataSource",
    "baseURL": "",
    "crud": true,
    "connector": "rest",
    "debug": false,
    "options": {
      "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "strictSSL": false
    },
    "operations": [{
      "template": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
        "options": {
          "strictSSL": true,
          "useQuerystring": true
        }
      },
      "functions": {
        "notify": ["title", "text", "click_action", "keyname", "to"]
      }
    }]
  }
```

> **Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot create data source "restDataSource": Cannot initialize connector "rest": Cannot read property 'root' of undefined
    at /home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-connector-rest/lib/rest-connector.js:93:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-connector-rest/lib/rest-connector.js:87:22
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-connector-rest/lib/rest-connector.js:52:25)
    at DataSource.setup (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:493:19)
    at new DataSource (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:138:8)
    at Registry.createDataSource (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:364:12)
    at dataSourcesFromConfig (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:570:19)
    at Function.app.dataSource (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:269:14)
    at /home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:191:9
    at /home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:282:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachKeyedObject (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:281:20)
    at setupDataSources (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:181:3)
    at execute (/home/veena-msl/Documents/care-doc-api/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:39:3)
```

Comment: Can you please post the datasource configuration for the REST connector? Just make sure to remove any sensitive information, like passwords etc.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš I posted the datasource configuration. Can you please check it?

Comment: Thank you. I don't see any obvious problem in your datasource configuration. Can you please post the full stack trace of the error you are receiving?

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš Posted complete stack trace of error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `functions` section, you have defined a function `notify` accepting several input arguments: `title`, `text`, `click_action`, `keyname`, `to`. However, the `template` section does not provide any information on how to map those arguments to an HTTP request. For example, is the `title` supposed to be sent via URL query or in the request body?

IIUC, you are trying to use the legacy Firbase Cloud Messaging HTTP API as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref Based on that documentation, I think all arguments of your function should be sent in the request body.

It looks like LoopBack's REST connector is not correctly detecting and handling the situation when an input argument is not mapped to any HTTP source. It should not be crashing, feel free to open a bug report in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-rest/issues

Here is a configuration that does not crash the server. I don't have a Firebase account to verify that it's working as expected.

```
    "template": {
      "method": "POST",
      "url": "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
      "options": {
        "strictSSL": true,
        "useQuerystring": true
      },
      "body": {
        "title": "{title:string}",
        "text": "{text:string}",
        "click_action": "{click_action:string}",
        "keyname": "{keyname:string}",
        "to": "{to:string}"
      }
    },
```

You can learn more about different ways how to configure input arguments in the connector documentation: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/REST-connector.html#defining-a-custom-method-using-a-template